# ArcGIS Javascript API - Add Labels with no symbology to graphics layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, labeling, feature-layer

Is it possible to create a feature layer that has no graphics, except for labels?

The idea is that I've already got my layer drawn from a dynamic layer type, and don't want to cover up that symbology, I only want to add labels.

This is what I have so far, but it is using the symbology defined for the layer, which I would rather have it use no symbology.

```
  var serviceURL = this.activeLayer.layer.url + '/' + this.activeLayer.subLayer.id;
  var layerOptions = {
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
      outFields: ['*'],
      id: layerId,
      visible: true
  };

  var layer = {
      layer: new FeatureLayer(serviceURL, layerOptions),
      iconNode: this.activeLayer.iconNode
  };
  this.map.addLayer(layer.layer);


var renderer = new SimpleRenderer({
    colors: this.colors
});
var label = new LabelClass({
    labelExpressionInfo: {
        value: '{' + this.activeField + '}'
    },
    useCodedValues: true,
    labelPlacement: 'above-center'
});
var symbol = new TextSymbol();
symbol.font.setSize('10pt');
symbol.font.setFamily('Corbel');
symbol.setColor(new Color(this.activeColor));
label.symbol = symbol;

layer.layer.setLabelingInfo([label]);
layer.layer.setVisibility(true);
```

Comment: Perhaps set your color to "no color", make them transparent symbols. The symbols wont show, but the labels will have somewhere to display from.

Comment: That `color` is for the text color. The symbology is appearing as the default symbology for the layer from arcgis server.

Comment: set your symbology to "no color" then overwrite the service

Comment: I see what you mean. That would require me to have two different services. The service is being used to serve up a dynamic map service. I want to set the empty symbology on the javascript side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was simpler than I imagined, here is the code below:

```
var renderer = new SimpleRenderer({
     colors: null
});
layer.layer.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Edit: This solution appears to work in the app, however, when the map is sent to an Esri print service, the print service will throw an error:

```
Missing 'symbol' in simple renderer.
```

So it's not a complete solution and if anyone knows how I can fix this it would be great.

Comment: try passing a valid transparent symbol object to SimpleRenderer.